# Send something to your alt character in Guild Wars 2

Tags: guild-wars-2

What's the easiest way to transfer an item from my main character to an alt?

Coming from World of Warcraft I expected to be able to mail it to my other character, but this doesn't seem to be an option, giving me "Unable to find recipient".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're unable to send mail to other characters on your account. However, the [Bank](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bank) is an account-wide stash that is shared by all characters on one account. You can transfer items that way.

As a *workaround*, you could mail something to a friend/guildie, and have them mail your item(s) back to you. This mail can be opened on any one of your characters.

Comment: It can also be accessed from any crafting station!

Comment: Thx for the answer. I truly hope there's also an easier way - this would mean it's easier to transfer something to someone else than to your own character?

Comment: @Jeroen From the field, yeah, that's pretty much the case.

Comment: Yeah its similar to Diablo3 if you have played that you also have a shared stash and its the only way to transfer gear between characters

Comment: You can also transfer money to an alt at the bank. It's easy to miss, but in the bottom right corner there is a small button "deposit".

Comment: In fact, crafting *automatically* accesses your bank stash as well. This comes in very handy sometimes.